# thinning corrupts lines at border

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an black and white drawing of a curve. I have attached an example[image]

I a am applying thinning like to the line drawing by taking the skeleton. i do this as follows:

```
cv::Mat element = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(9, 9));
cv::morphologyEx(src, src, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, element);
cv::ximgproc::thinning( src, src, 0 );
```

However, if you look at bottom left and bottom right of the line, there is only one pixel going off the edge. When i apply thinning, the end ends up looking like this:[image]

I have circled the issue. As you can see, for some reason there is a "line" of pixels on the border. Why is this happening? After skeletonizing I still just want the line to go off the border as before, not "squish" into a line lik it did

Comment: to avoid this kind of border issues, you usually make 1px border around the image: `cv::copyMakeBorder(src, dst, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...)`, and then you crop the result to get the original image size: `dst = dst(cv::Rect(1,1, src.cols, src.rows)).clone();`

Comment: Can I change the way i am skeletonizing instead? I am just wondering why this is even happening in the first place. It seems like a lot of overhead to add and crop a border to fix such a small thing.